# Google Analytics Event tracking with FullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking, fullpage.js

I am trying to figure out the best way to attach unique

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','content block','click','section1 arrow']);"
```

event tracking code on each arrow as well as the slide bullets. I've seen code that can be loaded AfterLoad, but i need the event tracking. Has anyone done this before or know how it could be properly implemented?

Comment: Can you provide a url?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the callbacks then?